# What matrix would give a radial blur in circular motion?

Tags: blur

I've been looking on the internet and can't find a matrix filter example that would yield a blur like in the following image:

[image]
<sub>(source: [gimp.org](https://docs.gimp.org/en/images/filters/examples/blur-taj-mblur-radial.jpg))</sub>

Maybe I'm not searching for the correct keywords. I've found Gaussian blur matrixes and linear blur matrixes, but no circular. Therefore my question: What matrix would give a circular motion blur? Anything can do (5x5, 9x9, etc.), I just need to see the pattern of weights around the central pixel and adapt it to my matrix's size.

Comment: Radial blur can not be expressed as a convolution matrix, because the kernel is different for each pixel. But if you can convert your image to polar coordinates first then it is possible. This is why its hard to find.

Comment: I see. Yes, I can convert it, that's no problem. I didn't know the kernel was different for each pixel. Thank you very much. I will look into how to do it with an image expressed in polar coordinates.

Comment: OK, ill try to find time to device an answer for you in thet case. This might have a better home at stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks. I do realize that this question doesn't belong here any more. I will ask there if I have any specific questions on operations to perform on each polar pixel. Thanks again.